# Unable to install bsddb3 Python package on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: python, macos-catalina, berkeley-db

I've used Homebrew to install berkeley-db and am now struggling to install the bsddb3 Python package. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
bash-3.2$ BERKELEYDB_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db/18.1.32_1 pip install bsddb3
Collecting bsddb3
  Using cached bsddb3-6.2.7.tar.gz (437 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/ryonlife/.local/share/virtualenvs/peg-scrapy-pegbot-ndRdHu61/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/00/9r872f810sz481x6k9pqkldw0000gn/T/pip-install-03k5olgq/bsddb3/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/00/9r872f810sz481x6k9pqkldw0000gn/T/pip-install-03k5olgq/bsddb3/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/00/9r872f810sz481x6k9pqkldw0000gn/T/pip-install-03k5olgq/bsddb3/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/00/9r872f810sz481x6k9pqkldw0000gn/T/pip-install-03k5olgq/bsddb3/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/00/9r872f810sz481x6k9pqkldw0000gn/T/pip-install-03k5olgq/bsddb3/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        import setup3
      File "/private/var/folders/00/9r872f810sz481x6k9pqkldw0000gn/T/pip-install-03k5olgq/bsddb3/setup3.py", line 354, in <module>
        db_ver = (int(fullverstr[0]), int(fullverstr[2]))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'
    Trying to use the Berkeley DB you specified...
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick for me was using Homebrew to install berkeley-db@4, rather than berkeley-db.

```
brew install berkeley-db@4
BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --prefix berkeley-db@4) pip install bsddb3
```

Comment: Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 11.1.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this pre-release version.

Answer (score 0):

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

Error: You are using macOS 11.1.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this pre-release version.